How can I reinstall a partially installed Perl module?
I'm running Strawberry perl on Win7 and somehow the LWP module got deleted from all my lib folders. I tried to restore it with cpanm, but it says that it's installed. Nevertheless, the LWP folders show only 3 empty subfolders: authen, debug and protocol.
I downloaded simple.pl and pasted it in the LWP folder. My perl programs still can't find it, though I have the use LWP::Simple; command in the files.
How can I install a working copy of LWP without the cpanm hassle??

cpan. Then inside, use force get LWP to bypass the "already installed" check. Then install LWP. (IIRC. Can't test right now)

Re "but it says that it's installed. Nevertheless, the LWP folders show only 3 empty subfolders: authen, debug and protocol.", Those two things can't be true. If it says it's installed, it also says which version is installed, and the only place that version exists in in the LWP.pm file. So you're looking in the wrong place. I believe perldoc -lm LWP will tell you where the file is located.

Either cpan -f LWP or cpanm -f LWP will reinstall the module. If that's not working for you, edit the answer to show the output of those. As @ikegami noted, this installs the modules even if the tests fail (and that's the main use of -f). For very popular modules, it's unlikely that the tests are failing by the time it gets to CPAN. For less popular modules, that might be something to think about.
Also, if you trust that LWP passes its tests, you can cpan -f -T LWP to skip running the tests, saving you a couple of seconds. cpanm -f --notest LWP does the same thing.
If you don't want the latest version of the module because you were using an earlier version and you want the exact same thing, you can use cpanm to request a particular version. Get the archive URL from MetaCPAN (or wherever):
cpanm https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/O/OA/OALDERS/libwww-perl-6.68.tar.gz


cpan -f LWP and cpanm -f LWP will install even if there's a test failure. bad

Test failures from something like LWP are unlikely, and there are plenty of situations where I trust cpan-testers for that. Even then, what would you do if there are test failures? Not have LWP? You then have to go back to find one that's on CPAN and doesn't have test failures, then install that specific version (probably with cpanm).
